# Solution of a Fourth order nonlinear ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\lambda>0$ and $f\in L^2(0,1)$. I am looking for explicit solutions of

$$y'''' +\lambda y''+ y y'=f(t)\quad \text{in}\quad (0,1) $$
and boundary conditions
$$y''''(0)=y''''(1)=y''(0)=y''(1)=0.$$

I am particularly interested by the behavior with respect to $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Possible suggestion would be to look for a series solution:
$$y(t) = \sum_{n}a_{n} t^{n}$$
and attempt to find a recurrence relation for the coefficients.

Edit: note also that $yy^{\prime} = \frac{1}{2}(y^{2})^{\prime}$ which enables you to turn your equation into a third order (but still very much non-linear) problem...

Comment: its seems difficult to conclude using series because of the nonlinearity and the fact that for consecutive terms of the serie will be involved.

Comment: That's right - which is why you would get a recurrence relation between successive coefficients: it is indeed the non-linearity which leads me to propose the series solution in the first place, rather than look for a functional solution

Comment: Added a further suggestion to post.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$y''''+\lambda y''+yy'=f(t)$

$y'''+\lambda y'+\dfrac{y^2}{2}=\int^tf(t)~dt+c_1$